# How register service type for Microsoft.OData.Edm.IEdmModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, odata, nsubstitute

I have implemented and ODataControllerExtensions class for my test cases. I opted to use NSubstitue for Mocking the DbContext and Entities.

The problem is that when I try to get the ODataPath

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> InvokeForTest<T, TResult>(this T controller, HttpMethod method, string entitySetName, string relativeSubPathUri, Func<T, ODataQueryOptions<TResult>, IQueryable<TResult>> expression)
    where T : ODataController
    where TResult : class
{
  return controller.InvokeForTest(method, relativeSubPathUri, x =>
  {
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EnableLowerCamelCase();
    builder.EntitySet<TResult>(entitySetName);
    IEdmModel model = builder.GetEdmModel();



    string pathString = string.Format("{0}{1}", entitySetName, relativeSubPathUri);

    ODataPath path = new DefaultODataPathHandler().Parse("https://any//", pathString, new ResolverIndirection(controller.Configuration.DependencyResolver));

    var context = new ODataQueryContext(model, typeof(TResult), path);
    var options = new ODataQueryOptions<TResult>(context, controller.Request);

    // Run the expression.
    return expression(x, options);
  });
}
```

The Issue arises when I try to get the IServiceProvider

```
  new ResolverIndirection(controller.Configuration.DependencyResolver)

 class ResolverIndirection : IServiceProvider
    {
      private readonly IDependencyResolver _resolver;

      public ResolverIndirection(IDependencyResolver resolver)
      {
        _resolver = resolver;
      }

      public object GetService(Type serviceType)
      {
        return _resolver.GetService(serviceType);
      }
    }
```

The exception I get is.

> System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.OData.Edm.IEdmModel' has been registered.

I was wondering if there is a way to register the Service Type of the EdmlModel. I open to suggestions on how to do this differently if I am going about this the wrong way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replaced

> new ResolverIndirection(controller.Configuration.DependencyResolver)

With

> IServiceProvider requestContainer =
>       controller.Request.CreateRequestContainer(controller.Request.ODataProperties().RouteName);

But before that you have to register a new Service Route

> HttpConfiguration config = controller.Request.GetConfiguration();
>   config.MapODataServiceRoute(controller.Request.ODataProperties().RouteName, "/", model);

This is how the final source looks.

> return controller.InvokeForTest(method, relativeSubPathUri, x => {
>   var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
>   builder.EnableLowerCamelCase();
>   builder.EntitySet(entitySetName);   IEdmModel model =
>   builder.GetEdmModel();   HttpConfiguration config =
>   controller.Request.GetConfiguration();
>   config.MapODataServiceRoute(controller.Request.ODataProperties().RouteName,
>   "/", model);
>
> string pathString = $"{entitySetName}{relativeSubPathUri}";
>   IServiceProvider requestContainer =
>   controller.Request.CreateRequestContainer(controller.Request.ODataProperties().RouteName);
>   ODataPath path = new
>   DefaultODataPathHandler().Parse("https://any//",
>   pathString, requestContainer);
>
> var context = new ODataQueryContext(model, typeof(TResult), path);
>   var options = new ODataQueryOptions(context,
>   controller.Request);
>
> // Run the expression.   return expression(x, options); });